# What's the best replacement for a circa 2004 Apple Cinema HD 30"?

Tags: monitors

For about 10 years now, I've really enjoyed my 30" Apple Cinema HD (2560x1600). It's showing its age, and I'd like to replace it with something a more modern. What's the best replacement? Here are the features I'd like:

- large screen (>=30");
- matte screen or at least low-glare;
- mainly used for coding/writing; fast response needed, e.g., for games, isn't important;
- can be driven by a late-model Macbook Air.

I'm indifferent to the specific panel technology. Budget: up to $1600.

Comment: What is your budget?

Comment: Does the panel technology matter for you?  Do you prefer IPS's better color rendering, TN's faster switching, or is anything okay?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something cheaper, with great color reproduction and a beautiful design, take a look at the [ASUS MX279H](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Monitors/MX279H/). It retails for around $350 in the US. I own the smaller 23" version, the MX239H and it is a beautiful panel. The color is great with a relatively low response time of 5ms. It is one of the best matte screen coatings I have seen. The only problem with it is that the stand cannot be adjusted in height and it doesn't have a standard VESA mount.

If you want a professional grade monitor, look no further than the [ASUS ProArt PA279Q](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/PA279Q/). It is calibrated for the perfect color reproduction in factory to be 99% Adobe RGB and 100% SRGB compliant. It also is higher resolution than the MX279H (which is 1080p) at 1440p. The ProArt costs almost $1000.

Comment: Both of these seem to have lower resolution than my current monitor. Is my budget high enough for a 30" or better?

Comment: @Michael You can take a look at the ASUS PA328Q, it is a 4K panel that is also about $1000, it is pretty much on par with the PA279Q. I'm slightly worried if your Macbook Air can drive such a high resolution display.